# How to avoid major loss on performance using DDD in scenarios with lots of relations between entities?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

To explain my question, I'll provide examples using .NET framework and considering the following business rules:

- There's two main entities involved on a specific domain bounded context - **Company** and **Employee**, in which there's a one-to-many relationship;
- Eventually, a Company should **pay salary** to all of its Employees (consider this as our application use case, or command);
- When a Company pay salary to a specific given Employee, the balance of one should be transfered to the balance of the other (consider this as our business rule);

Now, consider three ways that we might take to implement this (please, ignore possible code syntax errors since I wrote all of this in markdown):

#### Option 1. Using a traditional data-driven approach, directly using SQL and tables OR using an ORM commands and queries:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION PAY_SALARY;

UPDATE Company c SET c.balance = c.balance - (
    SELECT SUM(salary) FROM Employee e WHERE e.CompanyId = '123';
) WHERE c.Id = '123';

UPDATE Employee e SET e.balance = e.balance + e.salary
WHERE e.CompanyId = '123';

END TRANSACTION PAY_SALARY;
```

This is the plain SQL logic, which will be accordingly built behind a function.

#### Option 2. Using DDD, with domain logic on entities and Repositories in persistance layer:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public required Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }

    public required Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public required Company Company { get; set; }
    
    public void ReceiveSalary()
    {
        Balance += Salary;
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();

    public void PaySalaries()
    {
        var totalAmount = Employees.Sum(e => e.Salary);
    
        if (totalAmount > Balance)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not enough balance to pay employees salary!");
        }   

        foreach (var e in Employees) 
        {
            Balance -= e.Salary;
            e.ReceiveSalary();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
// EmployeeRepository
public void Update (IEnumerable<Employee> employees)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Constants.connectionString)
    {
        foreach (var e in employees)
        {
            var query = @"UPDATE Employee e SET 
                e.balance = @balance,
                e.salary = @salary,
                e.company_id = @companyId
                WHERE e.Id = @id";
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", e.Balance);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@salary", e.Salary);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyId", e.CompanyId);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", e.Id);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
// ...
// CompanyRepository
public void Update (Company c)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Constants.connectionString)
    {       
        var query = "UPDATE Company c SET e.balance = @balance WHERE e.Id = @id";
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", c.Balance);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", c.Id);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
// ...
```

As you can see, the first approach have all of its domain business rules encapsulated in the database command, which is bad if we want to eventually change database providers. Although, all we have to do is to mount this SQL command and abstract it away under a specific method like `PaySalaryToEmployees(Company company, ICollection<Employee> employees)` . All the logic of the operation goes to the data access layer and it'll update the data accordingly there, with nothing being loaded and processed into memory.

In contrast to this, the second approach isolate the domain business rules from the implementation details - which is wonderful for complex rules. However, it needs to load the entire company entity alongside all of its employees into memory, perform changes again in memory, and persist everything in a more "generic" way, i.e. We'll lose efficiency on memory usage and SQL command performance, since the data access layer won't know exactly what changed so that it only updates correct data.

The question I ask is, is there a way to have the advantages of DDD approach without loosing performance? Because, from what I understand, memory and SQL command performance is a valid concern when considering the second approach for a scenario that involves, for instance, companies with hundreds of thousands of employees, with much more complex logic, eventually involving even more entities. One idea that I had is to inject custom logic into entities (idk how to call this specific behaviors - I've thought on Domain Services, Domain Handlers, Commands (from CQRS), Strategies, etc.). It would be something like this:

#### Option 3. Using a kind of "mixed" approach, avoiding the need to load related data into memory if we want to apply business rules

```cs
// Same implementation as before on Employee
public class Employee
{
    public required Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }

    public required Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
    public required Company Company { get; set; }
    
    public void ReceiveSalary()
    {
        Balance += Salary;
    }
}


public interface ICompanyHandler
{
    // The implementation of this should be the exact SQL code at the option 1
    void PaySalariesCommand(Company c);
}

public class Company
{
    private readonly ICompanyHandler _handler;

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; } = new List<Employee>();

    // A factory can be used to avoid providing an ICompanyHandler to every initialized Company
    public Company(ICompanyHandler handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    public void PaySalaries()
    {
        var totalAmount = Employees.Sum(e => e.Salary);
    
        if (totalAmount > Balance)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not enough balance to pay employees salary!");
        }   

        // The same business rule will be applied in memory as well, but only if the Company 
        // was retrieved with its Employees
        foreach (var e in Employees) 
        {
            Balance -= e.Salary;
            e.ReceiveSalary();
        }

        // After all validations, we perform the command and delegate the responsibility
        // to a specific data access provider
        _handler.PaySalariesCommand();
    }
}
```

Do you have any personal thoughts and experiences to share, in relation to system design problems like this? I'll aprecciate any contributions to this question.

Comment: You should eliminate the foreach (sequential update queries i.e. roundtrip) and instead create a single batch query. For example, Entity Framework Core makes such batch updates simple [Efficient Updating](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7).

Comment: However, you are using the old ADO.NET, that also supports batch updates (less gracefully): [Performing Batch Operations Using DataAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/performing-batch-operations-using-dataadapters), [Batch operations using DataAdapters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/batch-operations-using-dataadapters?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: While solution #2 is the cleanest from a design perspective, I recommend improving the efficiency of the persistence logic implementation before falling back to solution #1. Your code (design) is a perfect candidate for refactoring. Maybe you can even change the ORM framework to EF Core.

Comment: In general, ADO.NET is optimized for working with DataSet and DataTable.

Comment: Are you saying that I should do both handle business rules in the entity side, but also use a specialized Update that would handle a batch update for this specific rule using the corresponding tool (independently if it's ADO.NET or EF)? If yes, wouldn't we be spreading domain logic across different places in our code? Please let me know if my interpretation of what you said is minunderstood.

Comment: No, you should not alter the application architecture. You still handle the database in the application's persistence layer. Business rules are usually implemented by the business entities that are not the data entities that you use to map data between application and database. Solution #2 encourages the use of the Repository pattern in order to decouple application and database system. It also provides the chance for an abstracted API to handle CRUD data operations more conveniently (without using SQL directly). (EF Core does all this out of the box. It's a Repository pattern implementation.)

Comment: Now those repositories are responsible for converting between data entities and table structures that will be used to satisfy the ADO.NET data connector APIs. Like the actual SQL requests are hidden from your application so are the table data structures (`DataSet`, `DataTable`). Of course, you can distribute those table structures outside the repository - if this makes sense.

Comment: Your repository basically takes a collection of data entities and transforms them into a `DataTable` (each item to a row). This enables the data connectors to execute bulk operations. This avoids the round trips and will significantly improve the performance of your repositories.

Comment: *"wouldn't we be spreading domain logic across different places in our code?"* - We are currently only talking about data persistence. Not domain logic. Unless you are writing a ORM framework, database handling is not considered domain logic. It's data persistence logic. Domain logic (business logic) is the application model that represents the problem that the application is trying to solve. In an accountancy application the domain logic is the modelling of the accounting. The business rules describe how this accounting is implemented by the business entities.

Comment: Based on the architecture model you wouldn't even consider data persistence as part of the application core (domain/business logic). Rather consider it as an external service. In DDD the data persistence is part of the infrastructure.

Comment: Does this mean it's okay to create extra specialized methods like `PaySalaries` within repositories that perform normal CRUD operations (like Create, Get, Update, Delete) to perform these bulk operations with better performance?

Comment: Yes. Your repository would expose a `UpdateSalaries(IEnumerable<Employee> employees) ` method. To enforce bulk updates, you can define the complete update API to request a collection of data entities as parameter (and remove all single update operations from the repository API). Then internally the repository will know how to convert the `IEnumerable<Employee>` to a `DataTable` that it can use with the data connectors or adapters. The repository already has that knowledge as it has to explicitly execute SQL commands. So it already knows the database design.

Comment: Note, the more specialized the repository's API is, the fewer arguments are required in order to use it and the more verbose the API becomes. Instead of having a method `Update` that is configured via parameters, add specializations that replace the configuration and express their functionality better by their member names.

Comment: I recommend to refactor your code in two steps: 1) Add an `UpdateBulk` to the existing `Update` method (both have the same parameters/signature: `IEnumerableyEmployee>`). Then profile both methods to actually *see* the performance gains. 2) Remove the original `Update`method and rename the `UpdateBulk` to `Update`. Consider more specific and explanatory member names.

Comment: For example, `PaySalariesCommand` is misleading in the context of the architecture layer we are in. "PaySalariesCommand" is more a name of an operation implemented by a business entity that executes a business rule. or use case. This is not related to your question, I just felt like I had to point that out.